# remove accordian animation from checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have an table where I want to remove accordian animation from checkbox only. The checkbox should work as normal item. Sample example is present at https://jsfiddle.net/qxgz4pp8/3/

I have below javascript function defined for onclick event of checkbox

```
function selectA() {
    var checkedValue = $("#checkbox3").is(':checked'); 
    if(checkedValue) {
        $("#checkbox3").prop('checked', false);
    } else {                        
        $("#checkbox3").prop('checked', true);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no element having an `id="checkbox"`. You just see the accordion behavior... That script just executes the `else` part with no apparent effect. What you intend do do is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the things that make it an accordion from your jsfiddle example?

```
<body class="fix-header card-no-border">       

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                            <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
                            <label for="checkbox" onclick="selectA();"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">test</div>                        
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I want the checkbox to behave normally like getting checked and unchecked on clicking. However i want the rest of the row to have accordian animation. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: The accordion animation has to be triggered by an event. The event in your original code was the checking/unchecking of the box. So, I would have to go back to @Louys Patrice Bessette 's comment of "What you intend to do is quite unclear." You'll need to determine _what event will trigger your accordion animation_ and work from there.

Comment: My view display list of accounts. I should be able to check accounts via checkbox and do a collective delete operation(click of delete button). But the remaining row should have accordian to display some details for each member. Which part of it you dont understand, please highlight it.